# Tests failing in Jenkins but works outside

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, openejb

I have a test which tests Stateless Session Bean using OpenEJB. I am using Maven for build management. The test seems to work perfectly fine out of Jenkins (on command line) but fails after I added the job on Jenkins.

More specifically, my test is not able to lookup the EJB in the JNDI and gets following exception.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "global/slides/SlideService" not found.
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.xbean.naming.context.ContextFlyweight.lookup(ContextFlyweight.java:55)
    at com.diycomputerscience.slides.service.SlideServiceTest.setUp(SlideServiceTest.java:45)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

I wonder if running the tests in Jenkins somehow affects the JNDI? I know that Jenkins uses Maven embedder, but Surefire plugin forks the tests by default and it possibly not running inside the same vm instance as of Jenkins.

I am running the jenkins in foreground (java -jar jenkins.war) and also running with the same user as I am logged in so there is no permissions issue. Also I do not need Window Manager running as my tests do not need to interact with UI unlike Selenium.

The Java and Maven version I am using in both environments is exactly identical too.

Any pointers?

Comment: With the OpenEJB log output it might be easier to see what is happening.  Usually goes to System.out and is in the build output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this?

```
"java:comp/env/MY_JNDI_RESOURCE"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily happen if Jenkins is actually using a different Java JRE to run your application - try running it with an explicit path to Java. Make sure you test that command outside Jenkins first.

I've just had the exact same problem and it turned out that a Windows Firewall entry had not been created for the specific JRE that Jenkins used - even despite my adding a global port exception into my firewall.

I simply ran my Java application with a complete path to Java, added the firewall rule to my Windows Firewall when the notification appeared and then re-ran in Jenkins and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen recently and thought I would share what I uncovered. When my unit tests ran within Jenkins, the jndi path that OpenEJB was "figuring out" was different than when I built it directly in my maven project from my IDE, so it was adding the Jenkins created "workspace" directory to the jndi path, which caused the lookups to fail. So

```
java:global/ProjectName/ProjectService
```

would be the name in my IDE while

```
java:global/workspace/ProjectService
```

would be calculated for the binding name in Jenkins. I was able to figure this out by the OpenEJB logging.